# Knockout list won't add new item

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I've been tring this this code to add item in list but it won't work. what am i missing?

html

```
<form data-bind="submit: addItem">
    Add To Cart:
    <input data-bind='value: itemToAdd, valueUpdate: "afterkeydown"' />
    <button type="submit" data-bind="enable: itemToAdd().length > 0">Add</button>
    <p>Your items:</p>
    <select multiple="multiple" width="50" data-bind="options: items"> </select>
</form>
```

js

```
var myListModel = function(items) {
    this.items = ko.observableArray(items);
    this.itemToAdd = ko.observable("");
    this.addItem = function() {
        if (this.itemToAdd() != "") {
            this.items.push(this.itemToAdd()); 
            this.itemToAdd("");
        }
    }.bind(this);
};
```

Comment: Please be specific about "won't work" means, and tell us what you've tried and debugged so far.

Comment: The provided code seems okay to me. What's not working? How are you binding `myListModel`?

Comment: If you bind it right it should work. Code looks fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you've forgotten to add `ko.applyBindings(new myListModel());`

Here's working [version](http://jsfiddle.net/AL6GW/6/)